# Google App Script - Telegram Bot - callback_data of an inline_keyboard

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot

I don't want to use any library and i want to create the function that can react to a pressed botton of an inline_keyboard. I use webhook.

The following code works great for incoming messages but I need help to add the callback_query data.

```
function doPost(e) {

  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  if(data.message){//working great

    var text = data.message.text;
    var id = data.message.from.id;
    sendText(id,text);

  }

  if(data.callback_data){//this part doesn't work and i need help for this.
    //no help needed here :)
  }

}
```

Comment: If statements evaluate if an item is true or false. What does your data.callback_data evaluate to? In other words when you do Logger.log(data.callback_data) what do you get?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a callback function?

Comment: Ok, I am a noob, sorry for any mistake I will do. I know that with webhook set telegram sends some data to my script. My function works great to recive the message data but i don't know how to handle the inline_keyboards query. I mean my script can't react to a inline_keyboard_button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
var data1 = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).callback_query.<object>
```

[Types of object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery)